# Como puedo hacer esta funcion en BASH

Tags: sql, bash, curl

*Hola, estoy armando un programa en BASH que me pueda determinar si un sitio web es vulnerable a SQL injection, es decir si se puede inyectar sentencias SQL y devolver un resultado.*

**En la seguridad informatica uno de los metodos mas faciles de comprobar esto es ingresando en la web y en un parametro ingresar una comilla simple**

por ejemplo:

```
login.php?id=1'
```

*Si el sitio es vulnerable o tiene esta falla presente, el SQL devolvera un error de syntaxis y en muchas ocasiones es visible en el sitio WEB el error mas conocido es el siguiente:*

**`You have an error in your SQL syntax near`**

**Yo en bash quiero generar una peticion GET al sitio web a travez de CURL, acto seguido quiero que guarde los resultados en una variable y que pueda preguntar a travez de un IF o algo similar si por ejemplo en el sitio se genero esa falla de syntaxis del SQL
Entonces si efectivamente se devolvio algun eror como este:**

**`You have an error in your SQL syntax near`**

*Devuelva un echo que diga este sitio es vulnerable...*

**queria saber si es posible hacer esto y como podria hacerlo, muchas gracias.**

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia y no muestras un [mcve] de lo que hayas intentado. Saludos

Comment: Muestra por favor qué has intentado, como comenta @Mauricio. Si quieres hackear, al menos que sea con código propio

Comment: En la forma en la que está escrita la _pregunta_, me parece que tu no buscas ayuda para programar, sino que buscas a un programador para que realice la idea que tienes. Sugiero que vayas a un sitio donde puedas contratar a un programador para que realice la tarea que tienes en mente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar cualquier resultado que un comando lance por `stdout` de la siguiente forma:

```
resultado=$(curl www.google.com)
```

Para buscar dentro del stdout puedes usar `grep`, por ejemplo

```
echo $resultado | grep "testing"
```

Si la cadena existe grep te dará la línea donde está, sino te dará un error code. Puedes revisar el error code del comando anterior de la siguiente forma

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No ha habido error por lo tanto la cadena existe en la respuesta"
fi
```

Vale quizá la pena decir que puedes agrupar todo quedando así

```
if curl www.google.com | grep "testing"; then
   echo "No ha habido error por lo tanto la cadena existe en la respuesta"
fi
```